# Chrome-extension Javascript to detect dynamically-loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm implementing a chrome extension app. **I want to replace href attribute in  tag (on my webapp's homepage) with "#".** The problem is that the  tag might be dynamically loaded by ajax, and could be reloaded by user actions. Any suggestions on how to let chrome-extension detect ajax loaded html content?

Comment: Related: [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844565/710446) (I might not say duplicate, though; your goal here is much more specific that that question.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways to do it,

### First solution is handling the ajax requests

There is a [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) function in jQuery which handles all ajax request on page.

In `content script`,

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() { 
      alert('content has just been changed, you should change href tag again');
      // chaging href tag code will be here      
    });
} + ')();';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

### Second solution is listening the content changes

This is possible with [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events), again in `content script`

```
$(document).bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("something has been changed on page, you should update href tag");
});
```

You might use some different selector to restrict the elements that you're controling the changes.

```
$("body").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {}); // just listen changes on body content

$("#mydiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {}); // just listen changes on #mydiv content
```

Comment: Why do you do `script.parentNode.removeChild(script);` ? Won't this remove all existing scripts on the rendered pages?

Comment: I think it is just a clean-up step. The script is still there. Although you cannot debug using breakpoints, `debugger`s still got hit.

Comment: This is great ocanal :)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is outdated. As of now, 2019, Mutation events are deprecated. People should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Here is how to use it in pure javascript:

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: This is excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for tonight.   Btw, here are all [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#parameters) for the `config` var.